# How to stop AlertView from showing up by adding "Don't show again" button?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have an application with an alertview that shows up when the application launches to explain about the app function. 
On my alertView I want to make "Don't show again" button, so the user doesn't have to see the same alert every time he/she uses my app. 
So how can I stop the alertView from showing up after the user selects this button. Should I work on the appDelegate or should I work on the viewcontroller where my alertview will pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store a value in `NSDefault` for this, as we cannot change this on `UIAlertView`.

So once the `UIAlertView` has shown, set this value to something that represents "read", retrieve it in one of the App Delegate methods such as `applicationDidBecomeActive` and use it as a condition in a if statement for displaying the `UIAlertView`.

Let say you had an `NSInteger` = 0, which signifies "unread", once the `UIAlertView` is shown, set it to 1 and store it in `NSDefault`.

```
if(alertHasBeenRead == 0)
{
   //bring up alert view
}
```

And subsequently in one of the delegate callback, set this value to something else other than 0, for example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great hint thanks. But I want the user to Actively choose "Don't show again" button and ONLY after that I want the alertview NOT to show up anymore.

Comment: @abha I might be a little late on the answer but check out my answer below and let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alert"]]){


    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Information", @"The title of an alert.")
                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"Some text goes here.", @"The message of an alert.")
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"A common affirmative action title, like 'OK' in english.")
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {

                         }];
    UIAlertAction *dontshowagain = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Don't Show Again", @"A common decline action title, like 'NO' in english.")
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                    {
                                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"alert"];
                                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                                    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:dontshowagain];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Let me know if this helps!